# What are the benifits of using Higher order functions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I am learning about higher order functions[HOF] and lambda in Kotlin.

I checked the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html) but didn't understand it, I found one benefit of HOF:

```
You can perform any operations on functions that are possible for other non-function values.
```

so, What are 'non-functional values'?
and What are those 'operations'?

In a higher order function if a lambda is taking two parameters and returning a value, then can't we just use a function for it?

and what is the real scenario when we have return a function?

I have seen real programs in Kotlin, but I haven't seen any use of lambda or HOF in them.
I want to understand why, else many of the features would just go unused.

Comment: The doc you linked to, gives fold as an example. Does that not answer your question?

Comment: @DavidSoroko I didn't understand it. It takes a lambda but can it be done with a function instead of a lambda?

Comment: Lambda is a function. As far as HOFs are concerned it doesn't really matter if a function is a lambda or not, it is an implementation detail. Lambdas are often convenient and less noisy but that is pretty much it. The doc explicitly says that: "Function literals are functions that are not declared but are passed immediately as an expression"

Comment: The (somewhat broken) max example can be invoked without a lambda by: max(strings, ::compare)

Comment: @DavidSoroko Ok. I thought I was missing a lot.  thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a part of the Kotlin syntax that makes it more concise and understandable.
For example, try to imagine this code without using lambdas and HOF like `map`, `filter` etc:

```
val sum = listOfInts.filter{it % 2 == 0}.map{it*it}.sumOf{it % 10}
```

[Type-safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-safe-builders.html) is a cool thing too.

These functions are widely used in many libraries and frameworks, like Compose by Google. The first thing I remembered - [State hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) pattern.

Comment: If you define the functions isEven, pow2 and mod10, then your code becomes: val sum = listOfInts.filter(::isEven).map{::pow2}.sumOf(::mod10). It is debatable what version is more readable.

Comment: @DavidSoroko If you add the declaration of these functions to tour code, then it will definitely be less concise. And the question is not about lambdas, but rather about higher-order functions. Without them, this code will lose both conciseness and readability.